# Anonymous "likes/reactions" using Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Question from junior Padawan to real Jedy.

I'm developing a website for a designer portfolio. Without any registration and backend. I'm using Firebase instead. I need to add a feature to collect "likes" (reactions) from anonymous users on works/posts.

Firebase RTDB structure:

```
+artworks:
  +someArtWorkID1: 
     name: "lorem ipsum"
     description: "lorem ipsum"
     date: "01.01.1970"
     src: "here should be url to picture"
     **likes**: (?)
```

Idk how to implement it. Should it be a simple number or array of UIDs (anonymous user ID)?

Or another structure:

```
 +artworks...
 +likes:
   +idOfArtwork:
     uid: true,
     uid2: true
     ..........
```

But in that case, how can I calculate the sum of "likes" for specific post/artwork?

Also, I am new to Firebase and haven't any ideas how to write rules for it. In order for the anonymous user could add/delete only his UID in the likes array. Or should I use another solution for this task? Help me please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or array of UIDs (anonymous user IDs)

That's one of the best options you can have. Each time a user likes an artwork, add the UID in a node, and if the retracts the like, remove the UID from that node.

> But in that case how can I calculate the sum of "likes"?

Simply reading the node and counting the number of children. Alternatively, you can also increment/decrement a separate counter if you want, for a simpler read.

Comment: Thank you! " Alternatively, you can also increment/decrement a separate counter if you want, for a simpler read." Sounds really helpful. But how can i reach that?Should i use "firebase functions" ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Cloud Functions. How? Simply by listening to a particular node, and each time a new child is added, increment the counter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and edit my grammar mistakes in question)